# SharePoint - How to lock a WSP solution to a Site Collection? Server? And a farm?

Tags: sharepoint, wsp, sitecollection

I have built a WSP solution that I intend to sell to my clients. I can see that other companies sell solutions that are locked to be only used on a particular Site Collection or a server or a farm.

How can I do the same? Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Define the scope of the Feature in Site (Activates a feature for all web sites in a site collection)